# How to create a Diagram from a MySql database in Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I need to create to visualize some tables relationship in a diagram.

I use MySql and the MySql Workbench (v6.3). I have a current connection and I ant to see my database tables in a EER diagram like Workbench is supposed to open/create: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-vertical-toolbar.html

But online Oracle documentation seems to be obsolete, for the v5, not for the v6 of workbench, so I wonder if anyone already could build that kind of diagrams in the 6th version of mySql Workbench and how...

I can only create new diagrams via File=>NewModel, but no idea how to generate a diagram from existing database or at least add existing table to a newly created diagram

Comment: Please explain how the current documentation appears outdated so it can be remedied. Perhaps it's missing information? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html

Comment: @PhilipOlson: I needed to create an EER Diagram Here is the page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-eer-diagram-editor.html I don't see any reference to the possibility to create it from existing database. More than that, I don't see the mentioned buttons or icons having open a mysql instance database. Is not very clear if a model (mwb) should be created first... The interface and icons are different when a model is open

Comment: Thanks for the comments, related information was added in a few different places.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to to "Database" Menu option
2. Select the "Reverse Engineer" option.
3. A wizard will be open and it will generate the ER Diagram for you

OR

Go through  the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5Q0lz5FkW0

Keep in mind MySQL Workbench derives relationships in diagrams from existing foreign keys. If your tables use engines that don't support foreign keys no relationships can be derived automatically.

Comment: The Youtube link is for the 5th version, so is useful but for the older versions of workbench users <6

Comment: Hi Santosh, THX a lot! You answered a question that I had in mind asking (why are the relationships not shown). Super!